# Scaling down and making image square in android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I need a way to scale an image down to 78x78. I have found ways of doing this by cutting part of the image off, like this:

```
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, 78, 78);
```

but I need to maintain as much of the image as possible. I had thought of scaling the image down and then making it square:

```
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageTest, 78, 78, true);
```

but of course this creates a square image that is squashed.

Can anyone suggest how I can create a 78x78 image that doesn't rescale and maintains as much of the original image as possible?

Comment: What shape is your original image? When you say squashed do you mean the shape is changed?

Comment: The alternative to "squashing" or resizing the image is to _crop_ it.  In this case, which part of the image do you want to throw away?

Comment: Various sizes. Always 150 tall or wide, but the opposite sides are always different.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The perfect solution would be to keep the centre of the image, but that's not a massive issue.

Comment: Calculate the vertical and horizontal centers, then add/subtract 39 pixels to a get the range for your desired 78x78 image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood, you should scale down and center crop the image. Try this code out.

```
public Bitmap scaleCenterCrop(Bitmap source, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
int sourceWidth = source.getWidth();
int sourceHeight = source.getHeight();

// Compute the scaling factors to fit the new height and width, respectively.
// To cover the final image, the final scaling will be the bigger 
// of these two.
float xScale = (float) newWidth / sourceWidth;
float yScale = (float) newHeight / sourceHeight;
float scale = Math.max(xScale, yScale);

// Now get the size of the source bitmap when scaled
float scaledWidth = scale * sourceWidth;
float scaledHeight = scale * sourceHeight;

// Let's find out the upper left coordinates if the scaled bitmap
// should be centered in the new size give by the parameters
float left = (newWidth - scaledWidth) / 2;
float top = (newHeight - scaledHeight) / 2;

// The target rectangle for the new, scaled version of the source bitmap will now
// be
RectF targetRect = new RectF(left, top, left + scaledWidth, top + scaledHeight);

// Finally, we create a new bitmap of the specified size and draw our new,
// scaled bitmap onto it.
Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, source.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dest);
canvas.drawBitmap(source, null, targetRect, null);

return dest;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Bitmap image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(testImage, (int) 78 * (testImage.getWidth() / testImage.getHeight()), 78, true);
image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, (int) (image.getWidth() - 78) / 2, 78);
```

Haven't tested this, as I'm on my way to bed, but it should accomplish what you want, so long as your image **has a width greater than or equal to its height**.

Regardless, I'd suggest you use BufferedImage instead of Bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here would be resize your image using the same resize rate for width and height keeping the smaller size in 78. After that you can use a center point based crop to get the middle of your image and making it a squared image.

```
        Image srcImage;
        int widthSrc = 150;
        int heightSrc = 180;
        float resizeRate = 78 / min(widthSrc, heightSrc);
        Image resizedImage = resizeImage($srcImage, resizeRate);
        int widthDest = 78;
        int heightDest = 78;
        int cropX = ($widthSrc - $widthDest)/2;
        int cropY = ($heightSrc - $heightDest)/2;
        Image croppedImage = cropImage(resizedImage,$widthDest, $heightDest, $cropX, $cropY);
```

If the image is already square you can skip the crop part.